# Unable to boot live Linux multiboot USB in UEFI

Tags: linux, grub2, uefi, multiboot

I have made a multiboot USB stick using multibootUSB, but I can’t get it to work. I think this is because it starts in UEFI, and I don’t want it to boot into legacy mode anyway. It just gives me the grub> screen, which tells me I can press TAB to list all possible commands.
[It should work](http://multibootusb.org/page_faq/#does-multibootusb-support-efi-or-uefi-booting), but I don’t know enough about grub to actually make it work.
So what I’d like to know is either how I can make the menu that lists all installed ISOs appear anyway, or how I can list and select them within the grub terminal screen. I tried to find this in the multibootUSB documentation, but I didn’t get beyond that it should be possible.

I hope someone can point me in the right direction.

Vasilis

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I contacted the developer and he provided me with new bootx64.efi file, which fixed the problem.

Comment: Would it be possible to link to the file? Otherwise, this question isn't very useful and it might be simpler to just delete it.

Comment: Well, he sent it to me directly, so I don't have a link to it and he will include it in the next release.